# Sounds doesn't play on Nexus 5 Android 5.0 (lollipop)

Tags: android, audio, android-5.0-lollipop

In my app i have the following code:

```
       try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(SOUNDS + filePath + MP3);
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            if (useMediaVolume) {
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            }
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(prepareListener);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            MonitorDataHelper.logException(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener prepareListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
};
```

And it DO work on pre-5.0 and even on Nexus 7 Android 5.0, but according to user reports it doesn't work on Nexus 5.

The sound files are small - move sounds for chess game. Windows show their length like 00:00:00, but they play fine. VBR is about 100kbs:

[image]

Before first reports i started play w/o `asyncPrepare`, and it worked on pre-lollipop, but didn't work on lollipop even on Nexus 7. Now it works on my Nexus 7(5.0.2) but according to users doesn't on Nexus 5.

Any ideas to try? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the reason of the problem: sound files that are less than 300ms in length are not playable in Android 5.0 on some devices(Genymotion Nexus 5/6 veryfied). So the solution was to create longer files by adding silent sound to the files itself.